Why are the “@” and “#” signs not accessible via the normal keys in Windows?
When typing on my Lenovo laptop I had ocassion to want to type the @ and the # symbols. I pressed the relevant keys for this.
The symbols that were displayed when I did this were " and | respectively. I have discovered that to get the @ and # sign I must now type the number 2 and number 3 respectively with the upper case button pressed at the same time.
Can anybody please assist as to why this has happened  or suggest how I can get them back t their correct position on the keyboard.
I have tried to reinstall the driver for my keyboard which is running Windows 10.

It has nothing to do with drivers. It's just a mismatched keyboard layout. Make sure to choose the correct one in settings.

If your keyboard has the @ and # keys on the middle row of keys, on the right next to the enter key, but to access those characters you need to press the 2 and 3 keys respectively, then it sounds like your physical keyboard is a UK keyboard, eg "English (United Kingdom)", but Windows is currently using "English (United States)".
If so have you checked your language settings (search for "language" on the start menu to find) to make sure your display/keyboard/region is set to the UK and not USA?

Thanks for all the replies. I have changed the language to UK English as advised and this has resolved the problem. Many thanks to all for your input.
